# Pandas MultiIndex manipulation

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm not very adept at Python, but I have a "bandaid" solution to a problem and trying to find out if there is a better way to do things. I have a dataframe of stocks I download from pandas_datareader. This gives me a MultiIndex df, and I'm trying to exact just the attributes that I want.

The initial df from pandas_datareader results in the following structure:

[image]

I'm interested in getting just the "High" and "Closing" prices in this structure. To achieve this, I have done the following:

```
  df.loc[:, ['High', 'Close']]
```

Which gives me:

[image]

This is close to what I want, but not grouped by the stock, rather the attribute. To group the attribute by stock, I tried swapping the levels, and then specifying the columns I want:

```
newdf = df.swaplevel(axis='columns')
newdf.loc[:, [('BHP.AX','High'),('BHP.AX','Close'),('S32.AX','Close'),('S32.AX','High')]]
```

This gives me the desired result, but seems a very "hardcoded" and inefficient way of doing this:
[image]

Is there a more generalized way I could go about doing this? I want to be able to just specify the attributes (e.g. Close, High etc) and the result to be for all stocks in there (grouped by stock rather than the attribute). This Multiindex is not making it easy for me so any help you can offer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a rather simple solution.

`newdf = rawout.loc[:,['Close','High', 'Open']].swaplevel(axis='columns')`

Using this there is no need to specify all the stocks. I swap the levels in the code above but this may not be required by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index slice function to get it easily. Please correct the 'ACN' and 'IT' as I tested it on different stocks.
References.[MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data = data.loc[:,idx[:,('High','Low','ACN','IT')]] # edit your symbol
data = data.swaplevel(axis='columns')
data.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)

data.head()
    ACN IT
Close   High    Close   High
Date                
2020-03-31  163.259995  169.880005  99.570000   109.160004
2020-04-01  154.679993  160.820007  93.290001   96.209999
2020-04-02  156.270004  160.500000  94.099998   94.919998
2020-04-03  152.149994  158.720001  91.820000   94.290001
2020-04-06  166.050003  166.750000  99.860001   100.940002
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, what about a scenario where one may have 100's of stocks. In this case, it wouldn't be feasible to type out all the stocks by hand. I tried the following to get it for all stocks, but can't quite figure out how to modify it for more than one attribute:

`newdf.iloc[:, newdf.columns.get_level_values(1)=='High']`

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I don't know if I can take that approach. If you have a large number of them, you can modify the list obtained by `data.columns` and do something like `idx(::,vars_lst)]`.